# I can't seem to get list.js to filter items with multiple categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I'm using [list.js](http://www.listjs.com/) to sort a list of items by category. It's easy to make work if each list item only fits in one category, but I am struggling with making this sort correctly if something is assigned more than one category.

[This is what I have so far on Codepen.io](http://sl.ookb.co/1HOT5AE)

Basically, I want to be able to tag things with both beverage AND game. I'm obviously not cycling through the array I've created for each item's categories correctly... So it only ever acknowledges the first item?

There isn't much help in the docs of List.js as to how to use it in this manner. I found an issue the list.js maintainer marked as closed that seemed related, but he basically just told the person to ask for help over here, so that's what I'm trying. https://github.com/javve/list.js/issues/189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem

```
for (var i=0, j=tryThis.length; i<j; i++) {
  if (tryThis[i] == selection) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

If the first category fits, you return true, but if the first does not fit you immediately return false, preventing any more compares.

You should not return false within the loop but only after the loop, when you know that no category was a match.

===== UPDATE

```
featureList.filter(function(item) {
```

This call, does it change the list, or does it return the filtered list?

If it returns the filtered list (as is the usual way) you never saves the returned values?

To save values returned from a filter function you usually just assign the return value.

```
list = list.filter(function(i) { });
```

If this works in this case depends on the design of the filter function, but try it.

Comment: Good point, that was bad form to return false inside that loop. However, I still can't get it to function correctly even upon removing that.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense... maybe the values are saved at all and the function just runs with whatever is first regardless. So then how would one go about saving a returned value for use? Maybe I've dived too deeply too fast into this... I'm a relative newb when it comes to writing my own functions.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Your initial catch of the return false was correct, and then I had a problem in how I was splitting multiple values into an array, so they weren't matching properly with the selection terms... Thanks for the help.